# What's my score?

Tags: code-golf, math, array

The question score on Stack Exchange is the total number of upvotes minus the total number of downvotes a question receives. However, the reputation gained/lost for every upvote/downvote is different (eg. 10/-2 on Code Golf).

Given the total reputation earned, the reputation gained by an upvote and the reputation lost by a downvote, list out all possible scores  (unweighted, +1/-1 for upvote/downvote) the question could have).

### Rules

- The total reputation and the reputation per vote must be integers
- The upvote-reputation will be positive and the downvote-reputation will be negative
- Impossible question scores are not valid inputs
- You can output the possible question scores as an infinite list or generator, print each individually, etc.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins

### Examples

```
[total reputation, upvote-reputation, downvote-reputation] -> [question scores]

[28, 10, -2]  -> [2, -2, -6, -10, ...]
[34, 10, -2]  -> [1, -3, -7, -11, ...]
[11, 7, -5]   -> [1, -1, -3, -5, ...]
[82, 31, -11] -> [2, -18, -38, -58, ...]
[15, 5, -10]  -> [3, 4, 5, 6, ...]
[-38, 4, -9]  -> [-2, 3, 8, 13, ...]
```

Comment: Are we allowed to output the same score more than once?

Comment: @bsoelch sure, why not

Comment: "all possible scores the question could have" Might be worth clarifying that "possible scores" here means unweighted score, where and upvote is +1 and a downvote is -1.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 92 bytes

*-2 bytes, thanks to UndoneStudios* 
*-7 bytes, thanks to SuperStormer*

```python
lambda s,u,d:(a-b*2for a in count()for b in range(a)if(a-b)*u+b*d==s)
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY8xboQwEEV7TjGiwmQsYVgUguSbbGMvdoJYbGSbImdJgxQld0qZmwQbtkhlPf3veTMf38t7eLNm-9T8-rUGTbuf613MchDgccWhLwSVZa2tAwGjgZtdTShIZBnZCfOqCkFGHYukXJ9kOXDuSaadnWEMygVr7x7GebEulKfjd1AagvKhSBaceEv6DCDO9TfrVJytjzAFAIsbd3MKUZmB55iTFOzqqecTZYTz6ugCSKfElD1-5Xs1S7q6Q1YhrcmBzeUfMobPSNuTuhobhpSxR9piu2N1Im06vCB9ObHC2I0rpRWOQ7fteP8A)

*outputs a generator*

**99 bytes without using `itertools`**:

```python
lambda s,u,d:(a-b*2for a in N()for b in range(a)if(a-b)*u+b*d==s)
def N(i=0):
 while 1:yield i;i+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY9BboMwEEX3nGLECpOxhCGolMpX6Am6MbHdWFATGVCUs2SDVLV36rI3KbbJoivP03-jP75_X27zebTrp-ZvX8usafNzGsRHJwVMuKBsM0G7vNSjAwHGwmtG_Nz52Qn7rjJBjPYSyZdDl0vOJ5JIpTfT8IK0CVzPZlDA2ptRgwTzYg6c7VW_XpzVNGehDHte-w3wFdNpdMrX6BiGAODijN10H6KykqeYkhBsV_Qt7ykjnBfRBeicEn3y2Eo3NQl1ZYOsQFqSiNXxHzKGT0jrnZoSK4aUsUdaY71hsSOtGjwifd6xQO_6k8IJ8aPrGt8_)

### Explanation

Goes through all pairs `(x,y)` of non-negative integers and checks if `x` upvotes and `y` downvotes gives the right score

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 115 bytes

```python
def f(s,u,d):
 i=s<0;g=math.gcd(u,d);a=s*pow(d//g,-1,u//g)%u/g
 while 1:yield(s-d*a)/u-a-i*(u+d)/g;i+=1
import math
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBPboQgGMX3noKYNAHno4qOqaPlMHZAJc6oEchkzjKb2bR36rI3KfgnadmQH-_Bex-Pr-luunF4Pj-taWjxrYVsUIM1WBCkDJDi-j2pWn6tTffangX251XNdTSNNyziuAXKwLqdvNi4DdCtUxeJWHlX8iKwpiKqSWxpTVWE7UGQuK3UgbNAXadxNsi_u0X_-GgjtVnToee5b4CacUb6PM4SqeFvNbemWQ3O7kWQg-AhhGQRVIP7kveUEc6T1YvQxyzrPthvhc4aLHFpASwBmpIVs-M_ZAzegOYbFSlkzI3MdjWH3GGyIc0KOAI9bZiA9_pKS4V10P2vfwE)

*Direct solution, sadly longer than brute force*

*`from math import*` is not possible, as it will overwrite `pow`*

### Explanation

1. Solve `b*u+a*d=s` by using `s=a*d mod u` -> `a=d⁻¹*s mod u` (dividing out the gcd of u and d to ensure inverting d is possible)
2. compute `b` from `a`
3. The possible scores are `(b-a)+k*gcd(u,d)` for an integer `k`

Comment: What about `yield i;i+=1` or the other way round, if needed?

Comment: [92 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY8xboQwEEV7TjGiwmQsYVgUguSbbGMvdoJYbGSbImdJgxQld0qZmwQbtkhlPf3veTMf38t7eLNm-9T8-rUGTbuf613MchDgccWhLwSVZa2tAwGjgZtdTShIZBnZCfOqCkFGHYukXJ9kOXDuSaadnWEMygVr7x7GebEulKfjd1AagvKhSBaceEv6DCDO9TfrVJytjzAFAIsbd3MKUZmB55iTFOzqqecTZYTz6ugCSKfElD1-5Xs1S7q6Q1YhrcmBzeUfMobPSNuTuhobhpSxR9piu2N1Im06vCB9ObHC2I0rpRWOQ7fteP8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

-5 bytes (and even slower than before ) thanks to *@CommandMaster*.

```
∞Óʒ¹*OQ}ε2£Æ
```

Two separated inputs \$[upvoteRep,downvoteRep]\$ and \$totalRep\$.
Outputs an infinite list that includes duplicated items.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASYA2f9vc2FiaWX//@KInsOTypLCuSpPUX3OtTLCo8OG//9bMiwtMV0KMg) (Extremely slow brute-force that barely outputs the first two unique terms of the example test case, so no test suite with all test cases.)

We can prevent the duplicated items for +2 bytes by adding a trailing `}Ù`:
[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//@KInsOTypLCuSpPUX3OtTLCo8OGfcOZ//9bMiwtMV0KMg)

**Earlier 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer (partially also by *@CommandMaster*) that's a lot faster:**

```
∞Ý€ã€`ʒ¹*OQ}€Æ
```

Similar I/O as above.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w3MfNa05vBhIJJyadGinln9gLUig7f//aEMDHV2jWC4jCwA).

We can prevent the duplicated items for +1 byte this time by adding a trailing `Ù`:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w3MfNa05vBhIJJyadGinln9gLUig7fDM//@jDQ10dI1iuYwsAA) or [verify the first five values of all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWXCo4ZZoWH/H3XMOzz3UdOaw4uBRMKpSRFa/pGBtSCBtv@HZ5oeWqzzPzrayELH0EBH1yhWJ9rYBM40NNQx19E1BbIsjHSMDXV0DQ1BoqY6pkCmAZCpa2yhY6KjawlkGukYAQVjYwE).

**Explanation:**

```python
∞        # Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 Ó       # Convert each to a list of exponents of its prime factorization:
         #  [[],[1],[0,1],[2],[0,0,1],[1,1],[0,0,0,1],[3],[0,2],[1,0,1],...]
ʒ¹*OQ}   # Only keep all valid lists for the given inputs:
ʒ    }   #  Filter this infinite list of lists by:
 ¹*      #   Multiply the first two values in the list by the first input-pair of
         #   [pos,neg] (or if it's a singleton list, multiply its value by just `pos`)
   O     #   Sum this pair (or singleton)
    Q    #   Check whether it's equal to the second (implicit) input-integer
ε2£Æ     # Calculate the question-scores of the remaining valid lists:
ε        #  Map over each remaining list in the infinite list:
 2£      #   Only keep (up to) the first 2 values
   Æ     #    Reduce it by subtracting: [a,b]→a-b or [a]→a
    }Ù   # (optional) Close the map, and uniquify this infinite list of values
         # (after which the infinite list of scores is output implicitly as result)
```

```python
∞Ý€ã€`   # Generate an infinite list of non-negative pairs:
∞        #  Push an infinite list of positive integers: [1,2,3,...]
 Ý       #  Convert each value to a [0,v]-ranged list: [[0,1],[0,1,2],[0,1,2,3],...]
  €ã     #  Map over each list, and get its cartesian power of 2 to create pairs:
         #   [[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]],[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],[1,0],...],...]
    €`   #  Flatten the list of lists of pairs one level down:
         #   [[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0],[2,2],[2,1],[2,0],[1,2],[1,1],[1,0],...]
ʒ¹*OQ}   # Only keep all valid pairs for the given inputs:
ʒ    }   #  Filter this infinite list of pairs by:
 ¹*      #   Multiply the values in the pair by the first input-pair of [pos,neg]
   O     #   Sum the values in this pair together
    Q    #   Check whether it's equal to the second (implicit) input-integer
€Æ       # Calculate the question-scores of the remaining valid pairs:
€        #  Map over each remaining pair in the infinite list:
 Æ       #   Reduce the pair by subtracting: [a,b]→a-b
  Ù      # (optional) Uniquify this infinite list of values
         # (after which the infinite list of scores is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: -3 by [`∞<€Dæ2ù€Â`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Ucc8m0dNa1wOLzM6vBPIONz0/z8A) -> [`∞·Ó2ù<`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8Q9sPTzY6vNPm/38A) (although it's even slower)

Comment: `∞Ý€ã€\`` also works for 6 bytes to that part and is much faster

Comment: [12 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8w5NPTTq0U8s/sPbc1qAE3f//o3WNdAwNYrmMLAA) (taking the negative reputation first)

Comment: @CommandMaster Although your 12-byter is very clever, I'm afraid it won't always work. E.g. inputs `[-1,10], -3` will also include `[3]` after the filter, because `3*-1=-3` and the `10` in the input-pair is ignored. Thanks a lot for the shorter generation of infinite pairs, though! I had the feeling that could be shorter (and faster), but couldn't figure it out earlier.

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that. I think [this](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//@KInsOTypLCuSpPUX3OtTLCo8OG//9bMTAsLTFdCjEw "05AB1E – Try It Online") fixes that

Comment: @CommandMaster I think you'll need an additional trailing `(`, but it indeed seems to work that way. Although I'm not entirely sure.  It's hard to verify slow programs like this when it barely outputs the first one or two unique terms. 

Comment: It isn't needed, you can see with `[2, 2, -1]` as a testcase

Comment: @CommandMaster Ah, your inputs are `[up,down]` just like my original program again. I still had `[down,up]` from your previous 12-byter. My bad.

Comment: I keep being baffled about this alien-looking language being used to code something, quite amazing!

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>60</s> 49 bytes

```ruby
->r,u,d{0.step{|a|q=r-d*a;q%u<1&&q>-u&&p(q/u-a)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxBCsIwEAXQfU8xUAwqMzHTGKxoe5GSRaV2nUSzkLZnjymirob/@H9CvL3S2CRqA0YcJiUfz7ub5n72TaBh31/8Jl5ZCN9SFMJt/SFSv1uWVIKDsatqZIVU2eKT9REhA/yFGeGUwXyhrhB0RmL@dQyCWUXZYs2ka4T8ic4WoKQWOlpHCJk5HymlTW8)

For any number of downvotes, check if the difference between the score and the sum of downvotes can be divided by the upvote score.

Answer (score 5):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <del>127</del> <del>123</del> 93 bytes

Port of [@G B's Ruby anwser](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265165/110802) in Rust.

Saved 30 bytes thanks to the comment of [@c--](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/112488/c)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBCoUgFEDReauwRlovsEZB2F6epCCYheno6dr9NPqTy4Eb85uaDexCF7igzpvErGolQoaz8HLlxBC@6uLv@yFnGY550uOpVKQnupB6PlDtBsBZi/r/RyQ9qaUa/xrCT1VwCVK03fJ1g0XCvIq9th8)

```rust
|r,u,d|(|mut a,mut b|loop{if a*u+b*d==r{print!("{}
",a-b)}if a*u+b*d>r{b+=1}else{a+=1}})(0,0)
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZBNCoMwEIX3OcWrK60R1G5KJb1KiagQ0CjRbCo5e5rWf1o6i5nhzTcz8JTuB2sriUrI4tFxoXpf3SAuKYWea/GpAUYCF3U5oNEDOBji7CDlmzTpbdvNWwv2dAjHGRqhw88osnW8NqJy2B1qt/qOHCFDsvEGZd2XE83YF94pIYdannxvNB51TyPkQXZA@O@L43@ITNkQ4mxruJD@Ys3Ow/RKkcQUUep@Gmtf)

```rust
fn find_pairs(r: i32, u: i32, d: i32) {
    let mut a = 0;
    let mut b = 0;
    
    loop {
        let z = a * u + b * d;
        
        if z > r {
            b += 1;
        } else if z == r {
            println!("{}", a - b);
            a += 1;
        } else {
            a += 1;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    find_pairs(28, 10, -2);
}
```

Comment: [93 bytes](https://tio.run/##RclBCoUgFEDReauwRlovsEZB2F6epCCYheno6dr9NPqTy4Eb85uaDexCF7igzpvErGolQoaz8HLlxBC@6uLv@yFnGY550uOpVKQnupB6PlDtBsBZi/r/RyQ9qaUa/xrCT1VwCVK03fJ1g0XCvIq9th8)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>72 67 66 65 57</s>  55 bytes

-6 thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)! (Inlining the while loop by use of `(yield ...)` being `None`, in turn allowing for post-incrementing. Suggesting printing.)
-7 more thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)! (Refactor to a recursive function.)
-2 thanks to Neil (Since `d` is guaranteed to be negative `0<=r/d` may be replaced with `0>=r`).

```python
def f(r,u,d,p=0):r%d==0>=r!=print(p-r/d);f(r-u,u,d,p+1)
```

A function that accepts the reputation, `r`, the upvote delta, `u` and the downvote delta, `d`, and prints the potential scores forever.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/dToQwEIXveYrxwrRdp9jyExFTX8QYg9uiJASaUhL26RGKC65z05ye70zm2Iv/7ru0sG6etamhpg5H1GiVYKW710qJV@XulHVN56nl7lGzlwXi44Y9SDY7U7UfAQAF4Y3WVVtkYmUEyzQ1nPtxRRSI0lXNYML/EaYTgum0IgiEBe@r7T@rdqDsjYQseQeuQEZR3TvwZvDQdEADSpMCpUCeMNx0mt1qKfEJeX6VRYKpRC7l7ueYL1pcNU8LzJA/77643ceTXf82DCeq7H@r9c6tjneXjVynpqfDMdPZWH@Yf@IkjmPC5h8)** (Harnessed to halt printing early.)

#### How?

`p` is the upvote count and is initialised to `0` for the first call in the function's parameters (`,p=0`). Subsequent calls (`f(r-u,u,d,p+1)`) are each for one more upvote (`p+1`) and for the outstanding reputation (`r-u`).

Each call evaluates whether any non-negative (`0>=r`) integer number of downvotes is valid (`r%d==0`) and prints the upvotes less the downvotes (`print(p-r/d)`) if so (when `!=` is reached causing evaluation).

Comment: awesome, love the solution!

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##Vc7dasMwDAXg@zyFVhhImczs/LCsnfYipReD2K0hTo3nMrrSZ8@Sjg52LgSfdKETz/lwHOtp6q0Dh4lP3HMUTesCvg5@sGDWQTCpWJ7oud@ERyOi3yQ8CJ69HXqIKtAmPomZBh98BoGmKNwxQbafGfwIWMAcrDo2mlVF/Ou6@W9j@IVVe2dXcW1YGfN3b7mdre9WdccNq9fZS9k5Mfkxo1tdls9XkHe4bMtvH/E2HJbLnhjSx7i3eGtLRLut3l1XNP0A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: The challenge allows printing forever rather than using `yield`.

Comment: Thanks @xnor. I'd tried `and(yield ...)` at some point and it hadn't worked, no doubt I had a bug somewhere!

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY7dToQwEEbveYrxYkPrTrHlJyLaJ1FjcGmVhEBTSrL79FhaV9S5ac7M@ZrPXNznNBa1sevaKQ2aWFywQyM5beyhk5I/SXvX3Uhj@9ERwzzQR6@xJYpHQVer2uEtCCAhvMn2WYycaZOAn17DaVo2RQJvbNvPKuz3sFfD5mOY3tthJvQ5DYn0FZgEkSR6suDU7KAfgQSV5DUKjiynGLko/7IQeI@sumKdYyGQCfFzr7DyzK/MihpLZA@ev3uHCrL833XrEes6e4nmNprc7hd1Pinj9uOveJpl2cuY0vUL "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") by recursing

Comment: @xnor thanks! Will edit it tomorrow.

Comment: @xnor nice golfing as always. I feel like I should have spent longer now :D

Comment: If `r%d == 0` and `0 <= r/d` then given that `d < 0` you can determine that `0 >= r`, saving two bytes. Also do you have to use `!=` or would `<` or `>` work?

Comment: Good spot @Neil, thanks! The return value of `print` is `None` and there is no ordered comparison defined between `None` and `int` (or `float` previously) so, I think xnor's `!=` is optimal there.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 44 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζ≦⁻×⁺ηζ∧›θ⁰±÷θ±ηθＷ¹«Ｆ¬﹪θζ«Ｉ÷θζＤ⎚»≧⁺⁺ηζθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/NisIwED43TzHHKaSg6GEXT6IgghZZ9gWijU0gTWp@FCo@ezYpsqhzmu9nZr45CWZPhqkYt7oPvg7dkVu8lAvyisUHHhLes37pnGz1jp897qUOjsKv7LjDgwoOBYWhpLDUDW4sZz6vpTBJVM3bBHGr/VpeZcMz/@REmYtCDnATUnHAaQl3UpyNBaxNOmSaoEweGZIzS8XBSu1xxZx/35kNi6SvQ9fj2K0UZ3ZsH6T4f@BHtsKPoSm8Rs8hHjFWsy8yJ9V3rK7qDw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮηＮζ
```

Input the question, upvote and downvote reputations.

```
≦⁻×⁺ηζ∧›θ⁰±÷θ±ηθ
```

If the question reputation is positive, adjust it for the minimum number of upvotes required. If it is negative, just negate it.

```
Ｗ¹«
```

Repeat indefinitely.

```
Ｆ¬﹪θζ«Ｉ÷θζＤ⎚»
```

If the question reputation is a multiple of the downvote reputation then output the possible score.

```
≧⁺⁺ηζθ
```

Add both the upvote and downvote reputations to the question reputation. This allows the score to be determined solely from the downvote reputation.

Note that the behaviour on TIO is for `Dump` to pause 10ms since the last `Dump`, meaning that the script usually times out after printing 6000 possible scores. The newer version of Charcoal on ATO supports the `--nt` option which disables this pause, allowing it to fill the 128KB output buffer instead. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVDLSgMxFMXl5AfchlndgQQUXVS6Ki1IwQ5F3ImLdCYzCWSSMY8KI_0SN10odOf_-DUmY5HqXd1zzn2ce98OlWC2Mkzt9x_BN3TydXa-1H3wZeg23MJzMUWnWPzDQ8Qr1s-ck62-442HldTBEfwgO-5grYIDQfBQEDzTNdxaznwaS_BFpEreRghL7RdyK2ue-CMnihQEJwMvQiqO4bLAryhrjMVQmrjI1EGZ1DLEyiRlayu1hzlz_u_MVDCN-iJ0PYzZXHFmx3SHst8D7mUr_Gia4FPrycTu3W0qd_zS52NOtyonOKdU-_zpQK8m6BrRmx_5Gw) Link is to verbose version of code.

Comment: Great solution!